# After paypal payment,I don't get transaction details. in sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

My paypal payment completed successfully but after payment,I don't get transaction detail like transaction id, currency, price, item,receipt no etc...
before 15 days its working properly. but now its not working.

```
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-
    bin/webscr" method="post">

      <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="kin@kinskards.com">

       <!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
       <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

       <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
       <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Birthday - Cake and 
       Candle">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3.95">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" 
       value="http://localhost/PayPalDemo/PayPalDemoCancel.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" 
      value="http://localhost/PayPalDemo/PayPalDemo/Succes.php">
      <!-- Display the payment button. -->
      <input type="image" name="submit"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_addtocart_120x26.png"
       alt="Add to Cart">
      <img alt="" width="1" height="1"
      src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you even read their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass **notify_url** parameter like **cancel_return**.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/PayPalDemo/PayPalDemoPayment.php" />
```

Also you must set this URL in sandbox account in IPN section. Refer this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/